# Error CS1503 when casting covariant generic interface types

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Using C# 9, I encountered the CS1503 error when trying to cast from a generic type implementing a certain interface to that same interface inside a `Func`, where the return type is covariant.

Example code:

```
public interface ITest
{
    ...
}

public class Test
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<string, ITest>> constructors = new();

    public static void Register<T>(Func<string, T> constructor) where T : ITest
    {
        constructors.Add(typeof(T), constructor);
    }
}
```

The error is in the `Add` method: `Argument 1 cannot convert from Func<string, T> to Func<string, ITest>`.
Oddly, had that interface been a class, the cast works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior for covariance with generics, and it's to do with the representation of the return value from the `Func`.

When `T` is constrained via a class, the runtime knows that the value returned by the delegate will always be a reference - so it just needs to allocate enough space for a reference, regardless of what *actual* func type it was.

When `T` is constrained via an interface, but without the additional "class" constraint, you could pass in a delegate that returns a value type value, not a reference. That breaks all kinds of things that are assumed by covariance.

However, you *can* still use an interface - so long as you constrain `T` with the `class` constraint as well. Change your method signature like this, and it compiles:

```cs
public static void Register<T>(Func<string, T> constructor) where T : class, ITest
```

For more information about representation (and identity), see [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) and indeed his [whole series on generic variance](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/).